# Adding a number by clicking on polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, numbering

I looking for solution for getting a numbering an attribute call "NAME" by clicking on polygon. I have dataset with polygon and I want to get number like 1,2,3,4... etc. I done this with simple expression in calculator, but I want to select which polygon is going to be next in numbering by clicking on it. Can I do that with some plugin on Python code?

Comment: If you have the attribute table open you can select a polygon in the map canvas, then get the selected row to be at the top of the table, and then change the attribute value for that row. Does that work? Or do you really need the value to go up automatically in case you lose count?

Comment: it was working but now keeps saying this Type Error no matter changes to string all the values. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbKE8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbKE8.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using a layer `action`.

Right click on the layer, go to `properties` then `actions` then add a new action of type `python` on `field` and `feature`, and enter the following code.
Make sure to use the proper field name instead of `pt_id` at the line `fld = layer_obj.fields().lookupField('pt_id');`

```py
from qgis.core import QgsSettings
s = QgsSettings();
pt_id = s.value("last_id") or 0;
layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]';
layer_obj = QgsProject().instance().mapLayer(layer_id);
fid = [%$id%];
fld = layer_obj.fields().lookupField('pt_id');
layer_obj.changeAttributeValue(fid, fld, pt_id+1);
s.setValue("last_id",pt_id+1);
```

Basically, this code reads the last assigned value (or 0 for the 1st click), then adds 1 to it and save this new value in the targeted feature.

[image]

To use it, put the layer in edit mode, select the `info` tool, right click on the feature of interest and click on `set id`. You may have to pan the map or refresh the attribute table to see the changes.

[image]

PS: if you click twice on the same feature, the previous value will be overwritten.

Comment: Yeah! great! it's working! Thanks you :) Can I do some shortcut for this? For ex. I move mouse to polygon and click "ctrl+g" and set id is done?

Comment: @AleksanderRogowski I don't know for the shortcut... feel free to ask a new question just for this!